# How to disable popup dismiss while form is submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've a popup with id `#registerModal` in which I've a form, when the form submit is happening I don't want the user to close the popup until a success message is shown, the form submit is done through AJAX.

```js
$('form#register-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/user-register",
    data: {
      'first_name': first_name,
      'second_name': second_name,
      'email': email
    },
    $("#registerModal").modal({
      "backdrop": "static"
    });
    success: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal" class="register">GET STARTED</a>


<div id="registerModal" class="modal fade modal-white" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 10%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="register-success-message" class="alert alert-success fade in">
          <a href="#" id="register-alert-close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a>
          <strong>Success!</strong> An activation mail has been sent.
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="register-modal-form">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 register-heading">
            <center> REGISTER </center>
          </div>
          <form method="POST" action="/user-register" id="register-form">
            <div id="status-message"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
              <input type="text" class="form-control register-fields" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" />
              <span id="first-name-register-error-message" class="register-error-message"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
              <input type="text" class="form-control register-fields" id="second_name" name="second_name" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" />
              <span id="second-name-register-error-message" class="register-error-message"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
              <input type="text" class="form-control register-fields" id="register_email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" />
              <span id="email-register-error-message" class="register-error-message"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 regsiter-form-fields">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
              <input name="register-submit" type="submit" id="register-form-submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left btn-lg register-button" value="CONTINUE" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've included static property on submit, but it is not working...

Comment: can you include the basic `html` structure of the modal?

Comment: @RinoRaj I've included the html...

Comment: can you try changing the `submit` button to `<button>` and change the event handler `$('form#register-form').on('submit', function(event) {` to a `button click`.

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding the jquery `modal` close button and showing it after success event fires for `ajax`

```
$('form#register-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/user-register",
        data: {
            'first_name': first_name,
            'second_name': second_name,
            'email': email
        },
        $("#registerModal").modal({
            "backdrop": "static"
        });
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        success: function(data) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what is the way through which user can close the popup?

Comment: By clicking outside, once the user has filled the form and clicked the submit.. The submit function is happening in the back end. At that time, the popup should not dismiss on clicking outside..

Comment: did you try removing quotes from options - `.modal({backdrop: "static", keyboard: false });`